# How to reduce the height of Getx snackbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to reduce the height of snackbar which I used by Getx. As, title and message are compulsory to put, If I leave them as empty string, a blank space is shown. How Can I reduce that, I tried using Wrap, but it didn't worked. I just want to show a single line in snackbar. Can someone please help me?

Comment: you can wrap snackbarr with container and set height.

Comment: I don't think its possible with Get snackbar, instead you should go with default snackbar provided by ScaffoldMessenger.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the width of the snack with maxWidth argument but there is no option for height. And the message field is required in library.

You can use:

```
  Get.rawSnackbar(message: "Message")
```

It have only one required argument message and it will show in only one line.[That's how the rawSnackbar will display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCW8V.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can change padding property

```
Get.snackbar("title", "message",padding:EdgeInsets.all(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not that late but still posting the answer,

As per the Getx Snackbar documentation,

Title and Message are required but I found in files that if we gave a messageText parameter as an empty container or Sizebox it takes it and ignore the message parameter. The same applied to the title too.
It'll reduce the height of the snack bar.

EX:

```
Get.snackbar(
            "title",
            '',
            messageText: Container(),
            colorText: ThemeColors.clrBlack,
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
          );
```

Happy Fluttering